# Restrict Access to Posts based on Custom User and Post Meta Data

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, user-roles, user-meta, capabilities

I have a custom Post Type called *Club Pages*, and a custom role called "Club Leader". Club Leaders currently can only read, modify, and delete all *Club Pages* posts. However, there are many different clubs that have their own sets of pages in this post type, and I need to make sure that Club Leaders can only read, edit, and delete the pages in WP Admin that are associated with their specific club.

Currently, each *Club Pages* post has a custom meta data field called `club_name`. I'm not using hierarchical post types to represent each club because there will be about 100 of them -- all of which need to use the same template and menu, which seems like a super cluttered and unmanageable admin area for super admins. I'm not opposed to using child post types if I **need** to, though.

So, my plan was to add a custom User Meta field, also called `club_name`, to represent which club Club Leaders are associated with, and somehow filter the Post Listing in the WP Admin to only show posts that have the same `club_name` as that user. So I'm thinking the logic for this filter would be something like:

```
If User->Role == 'Club Leader'
 get `user->club_name`
For each Post
 If `post->club_name` == `user->club_name`
  return `post_item`
 Else 
  return nothing
```

I expect each Club Leader to only be associated with one club each, but bonus points your solution allows me to give a single Club Leader access to multiple clubs' pages, in case that changes in the future.

Also, I know I only provided pseudo-code, but I'm looking for the full PHP code solution.

Comment: How many clubs will there be?

Comment: About 100.. maybe 90ish

Comment: That's quite a few, so my initial idea would be too long of a list of checkboxes.  So you'd probably need a Select2 dropdown/AJAX search.  Are you familiar with how the works?  I built something similar where users were assigned a 'location' and then before displaying content I would run a location match check.  But that was just 5 locations.  Same method would work but a huge list of 'clubs' wouldn't be very use friendly.

Comment: Not specifically familiar, but conceptually, yes. Assigning a club to a user isn't the hard part, though. What I am not understanding is if I should be programmatically filtering posts in the WP-Admin area based on user/post meta data, or if I should just rely on the "capability" functionality that already exists in WP -- and I don't know what the syntax would look like for such a script in either case.

Comment: You'd definitely want to do a programmatic check as you load the posts into the post-list view.  So check the users for the assigned club, then load the list.  I'll post the method I used as an answer.

Comment: I posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a similar use case scenario, I had a client with 5 locations which could be assigned to the user.  This will need to be changed for you because it's based on location being assigned to both a user and a post, whereas you're just going to assigning entire posts to users rather than matching post meta.

```
function filter_by_user_club( $query ) {
  if( is_admin() ) {
    $user_id        = get_current_user_id();
    $user_location  = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'myplugin_user_location', true );
    $currentscreen  = get_current_screen();
    if ( $currentscreen->post_type == 'custom_post_type' ) {
        if( !empty( $user_location ) ) {
            $location_meta_query = array(
                'key'   => 'cpt_location',
                'value' => $user_location,
                'compare'   => 'IN'
            );
            $query->set('meta_query', array( $location_meta_query ) );
        }
    }
  }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_by_user_club', 9998 );
```

I'm guessing that this sort of modification would need to be applied for your method, if I'm understanding your structure correctly...

You would need to change the `meta_query` to instead query an array of IDs using `post_in`, like so:

```
    function filter_by_user_club( $query ) {
      if( is_admin() ) {
        $user_id        = get_current_user_id();
        $user_clubs     = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'myplugin_user_clubs', true );
        $currentscreen  = get_current_screen();
        if ( $currentscreen->post_type == 'club_post_type' ) {
            if( !empty( $user_clubs ) ) {
                //if you've saved the user club IDs as an array (recommended)
                $query->set('post_in', $user_clubs );
                //if you've saved the user club IDs as a string use this...
                //$query->set('post_in', array( $user_clubs ) );
            }
        }
      }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_by_user_club', 9998 );
```

Obviously a lot still to do to get the club IDs associated with the user, etc. but this will filter the club post type list based on the user.

We're using `$query->set()` and essentially adding an argument into that screen's default `get_posts()` query.  While the query here, by default, will grab all of the posts (paginated based on how many you set per screen), we're now telling it to only show `posts_in` the array we provided when we checked which clubs a user has associated with them.

Comment: What action would I have to hook into in order to use this properly? Also, can you explain how `$query->set('post_in', $user_clubs );` works to perform the filter? I ask because it doesn't seem like that line alone would work in all cases, but I may be missing something.

Comment: I forgot to add the action, sorry.  There's a lot more in the function I wrote that doesn't apply to your use-case so I only extracted the one segment you needed.  I have updated my answer.  What we're doing is adding query arguments to the `get_posts` query, so we hook into the `pre_get_posts' action.  We then also check to make sure we're in the `is_admin()` section and we also then make sure we're only doing this for that one custom post type.

Comment: Thank you so much -- This is really close to what I want, but its my fault for not being clear. The posts I'm trying to filter will share a meta key and value with the user. So, I need to use something like `$query->set('meta_query', $args);` instead.